# What does `@=?` do?

Tags: haskell

I stumbled upon this code in an open source Haskell project:

```
doVerifyTest i vector = testCase (show i) (True @=? actual)
    where actual = RSA.verify (Just SHA1) (vectorToPublic vector) (msg vector) bs
          Right bs = sig vector
```

What's the `@=?`

?

Comment: Probably an equality assertion for HUnit. [Hoogle is your friend.](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%40%3D%3F)

Comment: Note that Haskell allows libraries to define their own infix operators, like `@=?` in this case. So, `True @=? actual` is just like `f True actual`, where `f` is a library-defined function.

Answer (score 6):

It's an infix operator defined in [Test.HUnit.Base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-1.6.0.0/docs/Test-HUnit-Base.html), quote:

> Asserts that the specified actual value is equal to the expected value (with the expected value on the left-hand side).